# jquery ui datepicker and mvc view model type datetime

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetime, datepicker, viewmodel

I am using jquery datepicker on my view model

Here is my view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.JobStartDate, new { id = "dt1", @class = "input-block-level" })
@Html.ValidationMessage("JobStartDate")
```

and my script:

```
$("#dt1").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
```

Everything works fine if my date is <= 12, if my date is over 12, it will show me an validation error message saying "The field Start Date must be a date." (I am using jquery validation)

For example: date 16/12/2014 will give me the error while 12/12/2014 won't

Here is my view model:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name = "Start Date")]
public DateTime JobStartDate { get; set; }
```

I am suspecting that my view model is anticipating a date in the format mm/dd/yyyy while on my datepicker i specified dd/mm/yy, is there a way to tell my viewmodel that I am expecting dd/mm/yy format so that it doesn't throw an error message if date is >= 12.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can look at using the [jquery globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) or add the following to your script (assuming of course that the server culture date format is 'dd/MM/yyy')

```
$.validator.addMethod('date', function (value, element) {
  if (this.optional(element)) {
    return true;
  }
  var valid = true;
  try {
    $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
  }
  catch (err) {
    valid = false;
  }
  return valid;
});
$('#dt1').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

and please use `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JobStartDate)`

Answer (score 0):

Here MVC View Model:

```
    public DateTime? date { get; set; }
```

This is for script :

```
    $('.DatePickers').datetimepicker({
        timepicker: false,
        format: 'd-M-Y',
        scrollInput: false,
        closeOnDateSelect: true
    });
```

keypress event for readonly date picker

```
    $(".DatePickers").keypress(function (event) { event.preventDefault(); });
```

Answer (score -2):

You will need to create a custom validator. You need to modify your property to take a string value instead like this

```
public string JobStartDate {get; set; }
```

You will then need to create your custom validator like this

```
public class CheckDateAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) {
        // Validate your Date here
    }
}
```

After this you will just decorate your property as such -

```
[CheckDate]
public string JobStartDate {get; set;}
```

Here is a good tutorial on [custom validators](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/260177/Custom-Validation-Attribute-in-ASP-NET-MVC)

Comment: This does not do client side validation (and certainly wont solve OP question) and you should never use `string` for a date!