# how to resolve date picker format in mvc5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

Im working in MVC5 entity framework. Here some fields have date fields so I need to set data format. Here I using script and datepicker. Now I got a problem if I set after date of 12. I got error like "enter valid date"

Script used in views:-

```
$('#datepick').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', minDate: 0
});
```

Code used in views

```
<div class="row form-group">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    Due Date:
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.goodreceipt.Due_Date, new { @Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), @class = "form-control control-text  ", @id = "datepick" })
    @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.goodreceipt.Due_Date)*@
  </div>
</div>
```

I got error Like this"Enter valid date" the date must be with in 12, after 12 (i.e 13-12-2014) error will occur so onlyIi comment validation message but here I itself I got this error.

Here i want to finish this task.

Comment: date dicker or picker? :))

Comment: oh so sorry can you resolve this task??

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery ui datepicker and mvc view model type datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285458/jquery-ui-datepicker-and-mvc-view-model-type-datetime)

Comment: Note also you should not be using `@Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` - The value of `Due_Date` should be set in the controller and the `datepicker` plugin will take care of the formatting.

Comment: $.validator.addMethod('date', function (value, element) {
  if (this.optional(element)) {
    return true;
  }
  var valid = true;
  try {
    $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
  }
  catch (err) {
    valid = false;
  }
  return valid;
});
$('#dt1').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });  here i used this but it display date and time how to change only date

Comment: @user3819665. To format the date use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.goodreceipt.Due_Date, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control control-text" ....})`

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are different format of date..need some change as below and try again :-

```
$('#datepick').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'MM/dd/yyyy', minDate: 0 });
```

Comment: here i tried this also date should be december/16/2014

Comment: $.validator.addMethod('date', function (value, element) {
  if (this.optional(element)) {
    return true;
  }
  var valid = true;
  try {
    $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
  }
  catch (err) {
    valid = false;
  }
  return valid;
});
$('#dt1').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });      But it display date and time how to resolve it