# DatePicker and Jquery validation in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I'm using datetimepicker from this http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/
and I have this property in my model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

in View:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Date").datetimepicker({
        format: "d.m.Y H:i",
        lang: "ru",
        minDate: 0,
        onСlose: function () {
            $(this).valid();
        }
    });
});
```

and picking all date I always got Invalid Date;
Message : The field Date must be a date.

Comment: This is may be because of format mismatch between "{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}" and "d.m.Y H:i" try giving same format.

Comment: inside this datetimepicker - d.m.Y H:i - the same

Comment: you must look into this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285458/jquery-ui-datepicker-and-mvc-view-model-type-datetime/27286969#27286969)