# format datetime using jquery plugin to match model format

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Inside my mvc razor form I have inputbox for datetime. I'm using [datetime picker plugin](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#tp-examples) which allows me to enter date and time as well. I initialized this plugin script to format datetime as

```
$('.dateTime').datetimepicker({                
     timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
     dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
});
```

Datetime property inside my model (which I use in razor form) has dataannotation to format date as

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}")]
public DateTime MyDateTime{ get; set; }
```

Inside form when I select desired date and time my text box is filled with values like

```
28.03.2015 09:12:00
```

As far as I can see this datetime format suits my model datetime format but I'm getting form js validation error

```
The field MyDate must be a date.
```

Update: Inside form I'm already getting datetime in format which I need

```
28.03.2015 09:12:00
```

and if I remove dataformat annotation from my model properties than I cannot process the form back to controller it brings up datetime window to enter datetime again?

Does anyone has solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery ui datepicker and mvc view model type datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285458/jquery-ui-datepicker-and-mvc-view-model-type-datetime)

Comment: you should have the corresponding format set in the thread.currentculture.datetimeformat