# datetime jquery plugin - format date headache

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have viewmodel with property

```
public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
```

I want to apply [jquery datetime plugin](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#tp-examples) to that property

Problem is that I cannot force jquery plugin to format date in format

```
dd.mm.yy HH:mm:ss
```

which should represent

```
01.01.1999 00:00:00
```

How should I decorate DateTime prooperty inside model to match this format in jquery plugin?

update:
I tried following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.dateTimePicker').datetimepicker({                           
               timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
               dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
            });
});
```

and inside model to decorate property

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}")]
```

but problem remains.

On enabled clientside validation I'm getting `The field XXXX must be a date.` and when clientside validation is disabled I'm getting on serverside datetime property with default value 0 year (like nothing was selected).

Comment: The client side validation can be solved as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285458/jquery-ui-datepicker-and-mvc-view-model-type-datetime/27286969#27286969). Note the `[DisplayFormat]` you have used only applies to `@Html.DisplayFor()` - it has nothing to do with this issue (and if you had `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true` then it would only apply when you use `@Html.EditorFor()` to render the browsers HTML5 datepicker)

Comment: can you please post an answer having my concrete example in mind, when using datetimepicker not just date. I tried but I'm having hard time :) Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to modify the answer I linked to something like `$.datepicker.parseDate('dd.mm.yy HH:mm:ss', value)`, but I can't test it until tomorrow.

Comment: ok. I'll try. Anyway thanks. When you find time post an answer here and I will accept it.

Comment: tried, doesnt work. please post solution when you have time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Validation method as @StephenMuecke mentioned in his comment.
I would suggest a different approach and recommend **[datejs](http://www.datejs.com/2007/11/27/getting-started-with-datejs/)** library , the dude did a great job and the library is light but full of features that will save you a lot of time in the future.

Back to your question:
the code you have for the JQuery datetime format is correct and you should keep it, That will ensure that the formatting in the control itself is correct:

```
$('#StartTime').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
    timeFormat:  "HH:mm:ss"  });
```

For the validation, you can create your own validation routine with the help of **datejs** `ParseExact()` method. your code should look like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("MyDateTimeFormat", function(value, element) { 
    return Date.parseExact(value, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");

},"Please provide  the correct date time format");
```

Then you should bind the validator to your control in the page, your code should look something like this:

```
form.validate({
   rules : {
      StartTime : { MyDateTimeFormat: true }
   }
});
```

Where `StartTime` is the id of the `TextBox` and `MyDateTimeFormat`is the name of our customized validation.

Here's a [.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9eSQ3l) with an example.

Comment: please, take a look at this question, I'm getting default value for date  on post action. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831406/formatting-datetime-on-the-clients-sends-default-date-value-on-form-post

Comment: Did this solution work for the question you asked on the top?

Comment: I initally thought that it must be a good solution, I still think but something is missing, cause I'm getting on form post action formatted date as default value (01/01/0001).