# Change date format in mvc5

Tags: c#, jquery, date, asp.net-mvc-5, format

I have property:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]

public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

And I have bootstrap datepicker:

```
$(function () {

    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        weekStart: 1, format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    });

});
```

My view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker", placeholder = "Enter Drop-off date here..."})
```

I want that date format will be dd/mm/yyyy. In Internet Explorer and Firefox are ok. But in Chrome when I change day>12 is invalid format. How change format to dd/mm/yyyy in Chrome?

Comment: Is the error as a result of client side validation or server side validation?

Comment: client side validation

Comment: That's a function of `jquery.validate.js`. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285458/jquery-ui-datepicker-and-mvc-view-model-type-datetime/27286969#27286969) for 2 options for solving this

Comment: I add this jquery script and now always is invalid format. Maybe bootstrap datepicker haven't method -> datepicker.parseDate ?

Comment: I debugging end I get error:"Cannot read property 'parseDate' of undefined at Object"