# Stuck with Date format in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, date, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using JQueryUI Datepicker in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project. I want user to enter dates in mm/dd/yy format in Create and Edit views. This is what I accomplished so far :

This is my model :

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString =
   "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}",
    ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime ProjectDeadline { get; set; }
```

This is jQuery code in _Layout.cshtml :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.date-picker').datepicker({ dateFormat: "MM-dd-yy" });
    })
</script>
```

In create View I have this : 
[image]

In Edit View I have this : 
[image]

If I don't touch Date in Edit and hit Save, I get a warning saying :

> The field ProjectDeadline must be a date.

I tried many possibilities to have what I want, but that's the best I can get. I got errors in my most of attempts. Can you tell me how I can fix my code to get **mm/dd/yyyy** format in Date fields properly? Thanks.

Comment: Your error is associated with `jquery.validate.js`. If your not using the `mm/dd/yyyy` format, then you need to modify the validator. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285458/jquery-ui-datepicker-and-mvc-view-model-type-datetime/27286969#27286969) for an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had this issue multiple times, but I have come up with the `CustomDateTimeModelBinder` which looks at the `DisplayFormat` attribute and binds it to the model:

```
// <summary>
/// This makes the model binder able to find a custom datetime format
/// </summary>
public class CustomDateTimeModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var displayFormat = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.DisplayFormatString;
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(displayFormat) && value != null)
        {
            DateTime date;
            displayFormat = displayFormat.Replace("{0:", String.Empty).Replace("}", String.Empty);
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value.AttemptedValue, displayFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
            {
                return date;
            }

            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, String.Format("{0} is an invalid date format", value.AttemptedValue));
        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

In your application startup, wire it up:

`ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime?), new CustomDateTimeModelBinder());`

Comment: You mean, I should wire it up in Startup.Auth.cs ?

Comment: Yes or Global.asax, Startup.cs or what you use :-)

Comment: Thank you, I did what you said. I'm still getting an error. It still says it's not a valid Date. I changed in jQuery and model to `mm-dd-yyyy`

Comment: Where have you inserted the code, what value is the input (in the debugger)?

Comment: Maybe try adding the line without the nullable: `ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new CustomDateTimeModelBinder());`

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But there is one problem : After I create an object, I go to Edit View, the date looks like the image in the question. And if don't touch Date and click Save. I get : `The field ProjectDeadline must be a date.`. Thank you.

Comment: You have to format the date to the format you need in the view.

Answer (score 0):

try data-date-format = 'mm-dd-yyyy' in div datepicker :

```
div class="input-group date date-picker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectDeadline, new {     htmlAttributes     = new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "10"} })
...
/div>
```