# MVC4 with Entity Framework Invalid entry for EnrollmentDate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm following a tutorial from  [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application)

For some reason when I try to create a new user with a date it won't accept it unless the month is January between dates ranging from 1-12ish.

I'm pretty sure it's because of the ValidationMessageFor(in the User.cs) method which forces me to enter a date which month must be January and I don't know where to alter it.

[image: Enrollment Error]

[jquery.validate](https://mega.nz/#!LlMkBZJY!dq0EocxGKhX1GUvEgLyDrTRpV0CPYGStwMzHFOxQw4A)

[jquery.validate.unobtrusive](https://mega.nz/#!a59nkaZL!-uLjwcJC8iJyr3R8DLbViHR2EuUP0L2dGTXetIUeazY)

Comment: What is the culture on the server (looks like its one that expects dates in the format `dd/MM/yyyy`)?

Comment: It should be mm/dd/yy but it won't accept 1/13/2016 OR 13/1/2016. It accepts both 12/01/2016 and 1/12/2015 which is confusing me

Comment: Well what is the culture?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by culture but it uses a Localhost Database and SQL server. There's more information here http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: What is the language on your machine?

Comment: C# is the language I'm coding in

Comment: en.US Why does it matter?

Comment: Because different cultures require different DateTime formats. Do you get the same error when you enter the full year `2/18/2016`?

Comment: I don't know why but it works when I'm at home using my own laptop. I'll try it tomorrow to see if it works on my work computer.

Comment: Ok so it doesn't work at work. The system locale is English (New Zealand)

Comment: `en.NZ` expects dates in the format `dd/MM/yyyy` so `2/18/2016` is invalid, and to represent the 18th of February, it needs to be `18/2/2016` in order to bind on the server. However, if you have client side validation (`jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`) then that 'valid' date will display a validation error because `jquery.validate` validates dates based on the `MM/dd/yyyy` format. If thats the case you need to reconfigure the validator.

Comment: I edited my question and included the jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js files. Could you point to where I should be looking because I'm very new to this.

Comment: (1) Are you saying you did not previously have those scripts included? And (2) are you wanting to to enter `2/18/2016` or `18/2/2016` to represent 18th Feb?

Comment: (1) No I just uploaded the 2 files from my solution folder. (2) I want 18/2/2016 to represent 18th Feb. dd/mm/yy! Thanks in advance

Comment: OK, First comment out those 2 scripts for testing and confirm that `18/2/2016` is now working correctly (`ModelState` is valid)

Comment: What do you mean by comment out those 2 scripts?? If you mean paste the code here it's too big .

Comment: If you added then to the view, then just temporary comment them out so client side validation is not triggered. You need to first confirm that posting a valid date (i.e. `/18/2/2016`) is working and `ModelState` is valid.

Comment: I commented out everything in both jquery files but it still doesn't work. I didn't add those two jquery files to the view. They were already in there! I just uploaded them for you to see.

Comment: What do you mean _I commented out everything in both jquery files_?? I mean just to comment out the lines `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>` etc. in your view. And of course it works. If not then there is something else in your code which you have not shown us. But based on all your previous comments it clear you have no understanding of MVC, so I suggest you spend some time learning.

Comment: Yes I commented it out and now it works! Thanks! Yes I'm very new to MVC so I'm googling around but there isn't much of a complete course on it. Any suggestions where I should look at apart from googling?

Answer (score -1):

Add code into script

```
$.validator.addMethod('date', function (value, element) {
  if (this.optional(element)) {
    return true;
  }
  var valid = true;
  try {
    $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
  }
  catch (err) {
    valid = false;
  }
  return valid;
});
$('#dt1').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

Comment: No!! Never do that! It means you will never get client validation for anything. I meant to temporarily comment out the scripts in the **view** for testing. The `jquery.validate.js` file validates dates based on the `MM/dd/yyyy` so if you want client side validation for dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format then you need to reconfigure the validator orr use the `jquery.globalize.js` plugin - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285458/jquery-ui-datepicker-and-mvc-view-model-type-datetime/27286969#27286969) for more details

Comment: Sorry to bother you again so where abouts to I paste the code you provided in the question you posted? Anywhere in scripts\jquery.validate.js?

Comment: That code was associated with using the jquery-ui datepicker plugin (and would not work for a normal textbox). I suggest you use the globalize plugin as suggested in the link. And you never modify the `jquery.validate.js` file - you write you own script(s).