# datetimepicker with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, datetimepicker

I have following field in my ViewModel:

```
[Display(Name = "Datum und Uhrzeit der Vorstellung")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}")]
public DateTime DateAndTimeOfPerformance { get; set; }
```

And display it the following way in a partial view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateAndTimeOfPerformance, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="input-group date datetimepicker">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateAndTimeOfPerformance, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}",  new { @class = "form-control", @Value = Model?.DateAndTimeOfPerformance.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm") })
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateAndTimeOfPerformance, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Like you can see, I use Bootstrap's datetimepicker:

```
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: "DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm"
    });
```

But I always get the validation error:

> The field Datum und Uhrzeit der Vorstellung must be a date.

From my research on Stackoverflow I saw that it can be tricky with a DateTime but I didn't find an example that matches mine to see how to make this work.

Is there any way to combine MVC validation and Bootstrap's Datetimepicker?

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of your app's culture and uiCulture? You can set them in web.config. If not set, default will use en-EN and therefore your value cannot be parsed to a dateTime.

Comment: By default, the` jQuery.validator` validates dates based on `MM/dd/yyyy` format so you need to reconfigure the validator. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285458/jquery-ui-datepicker-and-mvc-view-model-type-datetime/27286969#27286969) for some options

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely an issue with the format of the value in your `DateAndTimeOfPerformance` variable. The control is not able to parse it into correct date time. Check the format.

Also, check the culture. It may be causing issues and jumbling DateTime into a format which datetimepicker is not recognising.

Use the control with datetimepicker and check the value being used. You can then go from there.