# Date of Birth validation keeps showing

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I am typing a `DOB` -  `22/12/1986` into my text box and the validation keeps firing. It says:

`The field DOB must be a date.`

My **MODEL**:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("DOB")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "@{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Date Of Birth is required")]
[RegularExpression(@"{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Date")] // below is a link
public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
```

My **VIEW**:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOB, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOB, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

In `MS SQL database` the field is: `DateTime`

Why does my validation say that the date i type in is invalid?

Comment: Your regular expression... Its not a valid regular expression (or rather would only match the literal string you entered) and I think you have the @ on the wrong side of the quote in your DisplayFormatAttribute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate Date in MM/dd/YYYY format in mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606121/validate-date-in-mm-dd-yyyy-format-in-mvc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the client side validation is that the `jquery.validate.js` plugin used by `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` validates dates based on `MM/dd/yyyy` format and your entering dates based on a `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

The specific code used in `jquery.validate.js` for validation is

```
date: function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
}
```

which depending on the browser your using will give different results (in Chrome, `new Date('22/12/1986')` returns `Invalid Date` but in FireFox it returns `1987-10-11T13:30:00.000Z`which is valid, just not the date you entered)

You need to override the `$.validator` to format dates in your culture. One option is to use the [jquery.globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) plugin.

Alternatively you can write your own script. Note that the following script is taken from my own plugin used in conjunction with a `@Html.DatePickerFor()` extension method that generates a datepicker. The extension method adds html attributes for the date format based on the server culture and is read with the `var format = regex.exec(this.inputFormat);` line of code that I have commented out and replaced with your hard coded format. If you only ever want the `dd/MM/yyyy` format, then the script can be simplified because you only need the 'little-endian' format

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Override default date validator format to allow culture specific format
    $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || globalDate(value).isValid();
    };

    globalDate = function (value) {
        // Initialise a new date
        var date = new Date(0);
        if (value == undefined) {
            // Return todays date
            return date;
        }
        // Get the components of the format
        // The separator can be forward slash, hyphen, dot and/or space
        var regex = new RegExp(/([dMy]+)([\s/.-]+)([dMy]+)([\s/.-]+)([dMy]+)/);
//------------- see notes above
        //var format = regex.exec(this.inputFormat);
        var format = regex.exec('dd/MM/yyyy');
//------------- 
        // Get the components of the value
        regex = new RegExp(/(\d+)([\s/.-]+)(\d+)([\s/.-]+)(\d+)/);
        value = regex.exec(value);
        // Check the value is valid
        if (value === null || value[2] !== format[2] || value[4] !== format[4]) {
            // Its not valid
            date.setTime(Number.NaN);
            return date;
        }
        // TODO: What if year entered as 2 digits?
        var day = Number.NaN;
        var month = Number.NaN;
        var year = Number.NAN;
        if (format[1].charAt(0) === 'd') {
            // little-endian (day, month, year)
            day = parseInt(value[1]);
            month = parseInt(value[3]) - 1;
            year = parseInt(value[5]);
        } else if (format[1].charAt(0) === 'M') {
            // middle-endian (month, day, year)
            day = parseInt(value[3]);
            month = parseInt(value[1]) - 1;
            year = parseInt(value[5]);
        } else {
            // big endian (year, month, day)
            day = parseInt(value[5]);
            month = parseInt(value[3]) - 1;
            year = parseInt(value[1]);
        }
        date.setFullYear(year);
        date.setMonth(month);
        date.setDate(day);
        // Check its valid
        if (date.getDate() !== day || date.getMonth() !== month || date.getFullYear() !== year) {
            date.setTime(Number.NaN);
            return date;
        }
        return date;
    }

    // Methods 
    Date.prototype.isValid = function () {
        return !isNaN(this.getTime());
    }
</script>
```

Side note: Your `[RegularExpression]` attribute does nothing and can be removed.

Answer (score -2):

Replace `.` with `/` at both the places as Ganesh mentioned - `DisplayFormat` attribute AND `RegularExpression` attribute.