# DateEdit doesn't work with custom date format

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, devexpress-mvc

I have this model:

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(DevExpressEditorsBinder))]
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Дата рождения"), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
}
```

And view code:

```
@*Html.EditorFor(s => s.Birthdate)*@
@Html.DevExpress().DateEditFor(s => s.Birthdate, settings =>
{
    settings.Properties.DisplayFormatString = "dd.MM.yyyy";
    settings.Properties.EditFormatString = "dd.MM.yyyy";
}).GetHtml()
```

The first variant (that's commented) works perfectly but I need to use DevExpress. And DevExpress `DateEdit` sends the correct value only if I set the `MM.dd.yyyy` format everywhere. Else, the validator output:

> The field Birthdate must be a date.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: The issue is related to `jquery.validate.js` which validates dates based on the `MM/dd/yyyy` format (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677035/date-of-birth-validation-keeps-showing/39682410#39682410) for an explanation). I'm not familiar, but I assume `DateEditFor()` has a method to parse the date so that you could use a solution similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285458/jquery-ui-datepicker-and-mvc-view-model-type-datetime/27286969#27286969)

Comment: Of course, it has. But I didn't know how to set it for DX DateEdit.

Comment: And thank you for explanation, I didn't know about `validate`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [DateEdit documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument12034), you may set custom edit formatting to `DateEditFor` using `EditFormat.Custom` shown below:

```
@Html.DevExpress().DateEditFor(s => s.Birthdate, settings =>
{
    settings.Properties.DisplayFormatString = "dd.MM.yyyy";
    settings.Properties.EditFormat = EditFormat.Custom; // add this line
    settings.Properties.EditFormatString = "dd.MM.yyyy";
}).GetHtml()
```

As @Stephen said, DX extensions client-side validation based on jQuery bundle, which requires `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` to be loaded on Layout page or view page. Hence, you can use either built-in validation or remote validation to check date format regarding to `EditFormatString` property (see references below).

Validation references:

[Built-in Validation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument12059)

[Remote Validation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument17294)

Related problem with similar date format:

[DateEdit - Bind to a nullable property](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T233038)