# jquery validation allows numbers for "data-val-date"/MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, bootstrap-4

I've have client side validation enabled with `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.unobtrusive.ajax.js` both referenced on my page. I'm using `@Html.TextBoxFor()` to create the inputs in a form.

Client side validation is working correctly except for the dates.

If I try to enter a letter, I get a client side error, which is great.

If I enter a blatantly invalid date like `02/77/2018`, I get a client side error just as expected/desired, like any other type that doesn't pass validation.

However if I enter just an integer in for the date (e.g. `111`), it passes validation. Does anyone know why?

Luckily it doesn't pass my server side validation in the controller, but all my other validation is done client side and i'd like to keep things consistent. I could write some custom code to validate the format of the date, but it seems like there has to be an easier way to make sure the input is in `MM/dd/yyyy` or `MM-dd-yyyy` format.

To reproduce the issue, refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g1KvzI)

1. Enter `A` in the textbox and tab out - a error message is shown
2. Enter `111` in the textbox and tab out - the error message disappears
3. Enter `11112018` in the textbox and tab out - the error message appears again
4. Enter `111` again and the error message disappears
5. Click save - the form is submitted and the server side error message is displayed

Comment: What the heck? "111" passes validation but "11112018" doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jquery.validate.js` plugin validates dates by calling `new Date(value);`

The actual function is

```
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/date
date: function( value, element ) {
    return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value).toString());
},
```

Whether this returns `true` also depends on the browser you are using.

For example, in Chrome

```
new Date('aaa') // returns Invalid Date
new Date('111') // return Thu Jan 01 0111 00:00:00 GMT+1030 (Cen. Australia Daylight Time)
new Date('11112018') // returns Invalid Date
```

in FireFox/Edge

```
new Date('aaa') // returns Invalid Date
new Date('111') // returns Invalid Date
new Date('11112018') // returns Invalid Date
```

Even more confusing is that if you were to enter `new Date('02/77/2018')` in Chrome, you get `Invalid Date`, but in FireFox and Edge it will return a date (but not the date you entered)

As a side note, I raised [this issue](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/issues/1792) on GitHub, but it was rejected. Note the comment regarding `date` will be deprecated in favor of `dateISO`, but this has not been incorporated into `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677035/date-of-birth-validation-keeps-showing/39682410#39682410) includes a script that you can use to give correct client side validation for all browsers.

Answer (score -1):

You can use regular expression to check the input against your regex.
This is just a simple regex, but you can build a complex one if you want!
Sky is the limit

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    [RegularExpression(@"^.*\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Only mm/dd/yyyy is allowed!")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: This has nothing what so ever to do with the question. And the property is `DateTime` so a `[Required]` is not necessary (its required by default) and `[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]` has nothing to do with validation

Comment: `[DataType]` is used to add the `type="..."` attribute and is only respected whan using the `EditorFor()` method - and OP is not even using that. Again, it has nothing to do with client side validation

Comment: Then why have you added an answer that has nothing to do with the question?

Comment: Changed my answer to give OP exactly what he asked for.