# MVC ignores culture settings in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, culture

I'm constructing a MVC website in C# for use in Denmark, and I have therefore set the folloving in my web.config files, in the system.web.globalization node:
culture="da-DK" uiCulture="da-DK"

When I try to enter the date November 21th. 2018 as 21-11-2018 in a "Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date ..." control where model.Date is a DateTime, I get an error saying: "The field Date must be a date."

If I enter 11/21/2018 it gets accepted as if the culture was "en-US", but as the site is intended for use in Denmark, the dates must reflect that.

I hav found plenty of posts across the internet with the same problem, but non with an answer that solved my problem - 90% says: "Set culture in web.config", but I've done it and it do not work.

What an I missing in order for this to work?

Comment: You are getting a client side error (because `jquery.validate.js` validates dates based on `MM/dd/yyyy` format), not a server side error. You need to reconfigure the `$.validator` - refer [Date of Birth validation keeps showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677035/date-of-birth-validation-keeps-showing/39682410#39682410)

Answer (score 0):

One of possible reasons is as follows: you send GET (not POST) requests to web server.

Your custom culture will be used only for processing of POST requests. For GET requests invariant culture is always being used.

But I would recommend you to post minimal working example here.