# Format date in asp-validation-for

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-core

How can i set the date format for an asp-validation-for?
The input is dd/mm/yy and i have set a min and max date but the validation message displays as yyyy-mm-dd.
[image]

Model

```
public class ValidateNullDate
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date is required")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}
```

> 

```
<form asp-controller="Date" asp-action="ValidateNullDate" method="post">

    <input type="date" asp-for="Date" min="2019-01-01" max="2020-12-31" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Date" class="text-danger" ></span>

    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-white btn-user" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I am not using a plugin to handle the date picker.
I am using jquery validation etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's difficult,the client side validation is that the `jquery.validate.js` plugin used by `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` validates dates based on `MM/dd/yyyy` format and your entering dates based on a `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

You can see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677035/date-of-birth-validation-keeps-showing/39682410#39682410).

I think the easiest way to achieve this error message is not to use `jquery validation`,because you write `min="2019-01-01" max="2020-12-31"`,when we submit,The client will automatically validate.

You can see the test:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will give this a go and provide feedback.

Comment: i implemented the above from the link provided and it fired ok but produced the incorrect result.
The validation message came back as 'Please enter a valid date', looking into the issue  it appears chrome is supplying the value 'YYYY-MM-MM' instead of YYYY/MM/DD and so the 'format' does not match the regex. How can I change this?

Comment: You can add your detailed code that is the error message.

Comment: But how do i change the error message itself? That is the issue for me. That post doesn't make that clear. I want the message  to say 'Please enter a date greater than or equal to 01/01/2019' and not 2019-01-01