# Mvc Editorfor to date format (dd/MM/yyyy)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I keep having this issue trying to get the right dateformat.

Image of the EditorFor:
[image: EditorFor]

I would like for it to be in the (dd/MM/yyyy) format instead.

Here is my Razor viewcode:

```
<div class="form-group" id="divtwo">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" ,@id = "endDate" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Model

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
```

I have also tried setting Globalization tag in web.config, didn't help either. Can you guys give me a hint in the right direction?

Comment: It needs to be `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` (ISO format). And its just `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.EndDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })`

Comment: Hey, changed [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] in the model, and removed the "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" from the razorview. Didn't fix the problem

Comment: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" ,@id = "endDate" } })

Comment: Yes it does! (and adding `@id = "endDate"` is pointless (the method already generates `id="EndDate"`). It will display the date in the browsers culture - which is what the HTML-5 datepicker it is designed to do

Comment: hmm ok, then maybe my browsers culture may provide the issue. is there a way to force a culture? and thanks for the tip with @id changed it now.

Comment: Only if your users change their culture on their device. And considering that the HTML-5 datepicker is only supported in Chrome and Edge, I would recommen you use a jquery datepicker which gives you far more flexibility.

Comment: yes, i agree Jquery datepicker is alot smoother. I will try out with the Datepicker instead. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Just also note [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285458/jquery-ui-datepicker-and-mvc-view-model-type-datetime/27286969#27286969) if you want client side validation

Comment: Thanks for all your help, it was my server that was set to a wrong lang as soon as i tested on my pc it worked. and i do want client side validation.