# jQuery data('datepicker').getDate() return Invalid date

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have this input that I am using for dates.

```
<input id="txtsdate" class="form-control" type="text">
<script>
$('#txtsdate').data('datepicker').setStartDate(new Date(TimezoneDate()));
$('#txtsdate').data('datepicker').setEndDate(Infinity);
$('#txtsdate').data('datepicker').setDate(sFulllDate);
</script>
```

until this point my code works well and i set normally the date.  But when i try to get the date from the input and i am using

```
var sDate = $('#txtsdate').data('datepicker').getDate();
```

am getting 'Invalid Date'.
I have read this article https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/923
but doesn't seems to help me.

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve]

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285458/jquery-ui-datepicker-and-mvc-view-model-type-datetime

Comment: @Kixoka i am not duplicate... If you read the article you mention it says "date 16/12/2014 will give me the error while 12/12/2014 won't" . i am not facing this issue, also  not describing this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Simply code to get input value of any text box using jquery

```
var sDate = $("#txtsdate").val();
```